# OpenGL version to start with (as of late 2014)

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es

I know nothing about OpenGL, but it turns out it might be needed for something that I'm working on (figured this out simply because I want some visual effects that need fast drawing - hardware accelerated).

So I'm very much troubled about which version of OpenGL to start coding for as of the current date? (September 2014 for future readers).

As of now, I have read OpenGL 3.x is the most available (read as: supported) version, even on very old hardware (i.e. designed for Windows XP). But, what if I develop for OpenGL 4.x, will my application be backward-compatible with 3.x supported hardware? Or does it just break there and only run on 4.x (and future?) supported hardware?

My use of OpenGL is not for a videogame or anything similar so I might never need advanced functionality (as of now I can't name any to give you an example of what I may never use, I hope experienced OpenGL people will understand my point). However, I don't think this is going to lower in any way the driver support required, am I right?

Please note that I might have used the wrong terminology and I want to start learning OpenGL which puts me in a position not so good to understand whether I might need *this* or *that* feature and/or possible requirements - I am in the need of real advice to get started and figure my way out.

Comment: My recommendation for widest support: Request a OpenGL-2.1 context, use the GL_ARB_framebuffer_object extension to get framebuffers (they're the only thing that went into core as late as OpenGL-3) and do everything in the "modern" style, i.e. no use of the fixed function pipeline, in the shaders no use of the built-in variables. That way you're making your code future proof but can also run on older systems.

Comment: There are also Vertex Array Objects that went core in 3.0 and those are necessary for the "modern" style. At least binding one at the start of the application is ;)

Comment: What do you mean with "modern style"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure this answer skips many many details and exceptions (so take with salt and if you disagree or have something to add, leave a comment :P), but... Each OpenGL version mostly just adds features, so if you start using a new features it might limit the hardware you can run your app on (and so the question attracted a downvote, when instead it should have attracted an explanation).

Basic drawing pretty much remains a constant, **with one very big exception:** all the stuff that was [deprecated in version 3 and removed in 3.1](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL#Deprecation_Model).

### Old, < GL 3:

We used to be able to do things like:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING); //fixed-pipeline lighting. replaced with shaders
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); //fixed texturing
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadIdentity(); glTranslatef(...); //builtin matrices
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); glVertex3f(...) ...; glEnd(); //immediate mode with per-vertex calls
glVertexPointer(..., myArray); glDrawArrays(...); //immediate mode with client side array
```

But even then we still had GLSL shaders and VBOs. There's a fair amount of overlap and the GL3 deprecation didn't instantly replace everything:

```
glBufferData(...); //buffer mesh data to bound VBO
...
glVertexAttribPointer(...); //attach data to myCustomVar (either VBO or immediate mode local array)
...
attribute vec3 myCustomVar;
varying vec3 myVarying;
...
gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelviewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
...
gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

### New, >= GL 3:

The new way of drawing removes immediate mode and a lot of these in-built features so you do a lot from scratch, adds a few features and syntax changes. You have to use VBOs and shaders:

```
glBufferData(...); //buffer mesh data
...
glVertexAttribPointer(...); //attach VBOs, but have to set your own position etc too
...
#version 150 //set GLSL version number
out vec3 myVarying; //replaces "varying"
gl_Position = myProjection * myModelview * myPosition;
...
in vec3 myVarying;
out vec4 fragColour; //have to define your own fragment shader output
...
fragColour = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
```

To answer your question, and this is completely my opinion, I'd start learning GLES2.0 (afaik pretty much a subset of GL3) because it's so well supported right now. GL2/immediate mode certainly doesn't hurt as a learning step, and there's still quite a lot that isn't deprecated. You can always just use GL 4 features if you find you need them, but as said the basics really only changed between the above versions. Even if you use deprecated features **you have to go out of your way to get a pure GL3.2 (for example)** context that disallows certain calls/features. I'm not advocating it but it's entirely possible to mix very old with very new and most drivers seem to allow it.

**TLDR:** 1. use VBOs, 2. use shaders. Just for learning, don't bother with an explicit version context.

See Also:

- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL
- http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts
- [List of deprecated OpenGL functionalities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573398/list-of-deprecated-opengl-functionalities)

Comment: For those who downvoted my post I think they either don't want to help or they know the answer and think people should read their mind right before posting. I really don't care anyway becuase your answer, jozxyqk, is the kind of answer I was expecting. As of now I would go about GLES2 because my application is going to be only 2D and lots of features added to OpenGL, as I could read, are intended for making 3D development better - not my case. I will check out GLES2 and OGL3 to see if I should go more about OGL3. Simple last question: can I use multiple contexts (2 + 3) in an application? thx

Comment: @BlindedInChains GL is always going to give you a 3D context either way but using for 2D is just fine. My experience with GLES2 explicit contexts is limited to webgl (easy) and a little android (not sure). In desktop GL definitely. You might not need to [\[1\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377359/why-use-multiple-opengl-context) [\[2\]](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21650703/1888983) though.

Comment: What's so special about GL 3.3? Isn't it GL 3.2 that introduced the compatible and core context?

Comment: @Invalid yes, got this wrong and have updated. thanks for the comment!!